# SumatraPDF, how to configure negative page spacing?

Tags: document-configuration, sumatrapdf

The file SumatraPDF-settings.txt has an option to change the PageSpacing in the FixedPageUI configuration, it accept values ranging from 0 to (very high number). The question is, if possible, how to set a value less than zero.

Comment: Please add a sentence to your question, what you expect from a negative value -- thanks!

Comment: I was expecting to overlap pages in dual page view

Comment: If anyone can close this question, is welcome to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the top left icon which gives access to menus, and select `Settings->Advanced Options`. Notepad will open `SumatraPDF-settings.txt`:

[image]

I tested: you can use negative values.

Comment: Ok, I've got it, It works know, I was using low values so I didn't appreciate the changes, thanks for your answer